# SQLAlchemy создание таблиц

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Вылазит ошибка при создании таблицы, код вроде ничем не отличается от приведенного в [документации](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#creating-and-dropping-database-tables%22%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%22). В чем ошибка?

Код:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://lab_6:lab_6@localhost:3306/lab_6', pool_recycle=3600)
connection = engine.connect()
metadata = MetaData()
regions = table('regions', metadata,
                Column('region_id', Integer(), primary_key=True),
                Column('region_name', String(45), index=True, nullable=False, unique=True),
                Column('region_population', Integer(), nullable=False),
                Column('region_square', Integer(), nullable=False)
                )
cities = table('cities', metadata,
               Column('city_id', Integer(), primary_key=True),
               Column('city_name', String(45), nullable=False, unique=True),
               Column('region_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('regions.region_id'))
               )
metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Ошибка:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:166: Warning: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xE7\\xE8\\xEC\\xE0)' for column 'VARIABLE_VALUE' at row 480")
  result = self._query(query)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:166: Warning: (1287, "'@@tx_isolation' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '@@transaction_isolation' instead")
  result = self._query(query)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/projects/labs/Новая папка/Lab_6.py", line 36, in <module>
    Column('region_square', Integer(), nullable=False)
  File "<string>", line 2, in table
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\selectable.py", line 1720, in __init__
    self.append_column(c)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\selectable.py", line 1733, in append_column
    self._columns[c.key] = c
AttributeError: 'MetaData' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте написать `Table` с большой буквы.